# file_get_contents time out

Tags: php

`file_get_contents` в какой то из версий php имеет проблему с закрытием подключений.

Как решить эту проблему не устанавливая заголовки во все использования функций (их слишком много)

Можно ли решить проблему на серверном уровне?

Comment: Можно. Обновите php до последней версии.

Comment: Стоит такая версия:
PHP 5.6.30-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2017 10:27:57)

Я честно говоря не знаю, как поставить иную версию от той, что предлагает сервер, и полагаю он ставит последнюю от той, что имеется.

Comment: "Дорогие учёные. У меня который год в подполе происходит подземный стук. Объясните, пожалуйста, как он происходит" (с)